# How to find the integer multiplicand from given two points?

Tags: elliptic-curves, discrete-logarithm

I have two points on an elliptic curve $P(x_1,y_1)$ and $Q(x_2,y_2)$ and a scalar value $x$, where $P=x \cdot Q$. What is the best way that I could figure out the value of $x$?

Given that I know all the necessary key and constants. (a,b,p,G,nA,PB...)

Comment: This is the elliptic curve [discrete logarithm problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm). The security of ECC relies on the hardness of this problem, so computing x will be infeasible for any curve considered secure.

Comment: If you want to compute this for a small curve, you could use [Pollard's rho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollard's_rho_algorithm)

Comment: my concern is for Image Amlitude (pixel value) which was previously multiplied to some random point P(x1,y1) to from Q(x2,y2)  so how can i get my pixel amplitude back during decryption.

Comment: 1) Are your `x` values small? 2) Why are you inventing such weird cryptography?

Comment: yes x is just for obtaining the Pixel values between 1-255 .